# jQuery :gt selector with relative indexing

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I have a `<dl>` list containing multiple `<dd><ol>...</ol></dd>` lists, each with some number of `<li>` elements. I'm trying to select all but the first 2 elements of each `<ol>` list.

I can easily achieve it by using

```
$("dl dd ol").each(function(){
    $elems = $("li:gt(2)",$(this));
});
```

I'm curious, is it possible to perform the same operation without using `$.each` (i.e. only using selectors)? I've tried `$("dl dd ol > li:gt(2)")` but it seems that `:gt` does not index relatively to the parent. Is there, currently, any way to do this using only selectors?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RtcH/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` method:

```
$("dl dd ol").find("li:gt(2)").css('color','#f00');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X28Kb/

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure it can be done by using only the selectors :( But here is another one way,

```
$('dl ol li:last-child').prev('li').andSelf().css('color','#f00');
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4RtcH/1/)